# Writing excel row data to sql server table, same row is getting inserted every time

Tags: java, sql-server, excel, apache-poi

[image: Input excel file with 2 rows]

[image: Output... same row inserted, but variable r shows correct number]

[image: Output... showing values of all variable.... same row inserted]

I have and excel sheet, wherein I have few rows which have to written to SQL server table. Here is my code..

I perform few conversions before insertion, like, converting dates, etc. Every time, the same row is getting inserted. If I check output the row number in for loop, I get the correct result, but the same row is inserted every time. Don't know where am I going wrong.  After I insert, I want to remove the row and write it to another file. But, I am not able to write it to another file. The file size is increasing, no rows are copied to another file.

```
public void runit() throws Exception
{
    boolean success;
    success = false;

    try
    {
        File folder = new File("c:\\DCIN_LOG\\dcp_dcl_mfg_order_status\\SQL DATA BASE DCP_2015\\SQL database  DCP.xls");

        if(!(folder.exists()))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input File Not Found");

        else
        {
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(folder);
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            System.out.println("rows : " + rows);

            int coln = 0, coln1 = 0, coln2 = 0, coln3 = 0, coln4 = 0, coln5 = 0, coln6 = 0, coln7 = 0, coln8 = 0, coln9 = 0, coln10 = 0, coln11 = 0, coln12 = 0, coln13 = 0;

            HSSFRow rown = sheet.getRow(0);

            for(int c = 1; c < 15; c++)
            {
                HSSFCell celln = rown.getCell((short) c, rown.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                if(("Sold-to pt").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Customer").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln1 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Purchase order no.").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln2 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("PO Date").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln3 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("SO No.").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln4 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("SO Dtd.").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln5 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Line Item").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln6 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Part No.").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln7 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Description").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln8 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Order Qty. ").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln9 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Zone").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln10 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("KAM").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln11 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Customer request dt:").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln12 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }

                if(("Delivery -Full/partial").equals(celln.toString().trim()))
                {
                        coln13 = celln.getColumnIndex();
                }
            }

            for(int r = 1; r < rows; r++)
            {
                HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
                System.out.println("r just in loop : " + r);

                if(row != null)
                {
                    int k = 0;

                    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell((short) 1);
                    HSSFCell cell1 = row.getCell((short) 2);
                    HSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell((short) 3);
                    HSSFCell cell3 = row.getCell((short) 4);
                    HSSFCell cell4 = row.getCell((short) 5);
                    HSSFCell cell5 = row.getCell((short) 6);
                    HSSFCell cell6 = row.getCell((short) 7);
                    HSSFCell cell7 = row.getCell((short) 8);
                    HSSFCell cell8 = row.getCell((short) 9);
                    HSSFCell cell9 = row.getCell((short) 10);
                    HSSFCell cell10 = row.getCell((short) 11);
                    HSSFCell cell11 = row.getCell((short) 12);
                    HSSFCell cell12 = row.getCell((short) 13);
                    HSSFCell cell13 = row.getCell((short) 14);

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();

                    String rt = "";

                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select RoutingTime from DCP.dbo.Routing_Time where PartDesc = '"+cell8.toString().trim()+"'");

                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                            rt = rs.getString("RoutingTime");
                            System.out.println("RoutingTime : " + rt);
                    }

                    rs.close();

                    st.close();

                    String val = "", val1 = "", val2 = "", val3 = "";

                    val = cell3.toString().trim();
                    val1 = cell5.toString().trim();
                    val2 = cell12.toString().trim();

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();

                    val3 = sdf.format(cal4.getTime());

                    cal4.setTime(sdf.parse(val3));

                    val3 = sdf1.format(cal4.getTime());
                    System.out.println("Current Date : " + val3);

                    cal1.setTime(sdf.parse(val));

                    val = sdf1.format(cal1.getTime());
                    System.out.println("val : " + val);

                    cal2.setTime(sdf.parse(val1));

                    val1 = sdf1.format(cal2.getTime());
                    System.out.println("val1 : " + val1);

                    cal3.setTime(sdf.parse(val2));

                    val2 = sdf1.format(cal3.getTime());
                    System.out.println("val2 : " + val2);

                    String together = cell13.toString().trim();

                    if(("full").equals(together.toLowerCase().trim()))
                            together = "Yes";

                    else
                            together = "No";

                    int index = cell4.toString().trim().indexOf(".");

                    String sonum = cell4.toString().trim().substring(0, index).trim();

                    int index1 = cell.toString().trim().indexOf(".");

                    String stp = cell.toString().trim().substring(0, index1).trim();

                    int index2 = cell6.toString().trim().indexOf(".");

                    String lnum = cell6.toString().trim().substring(0, index2).trim();

                    int index3 = cell9.toString().trim().indexOf(".");

                    String qty = cell9.toString().trim().substring(0, index3).trim();


                    k = stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO DCP.dbo.DCPDate(PO, PODate, SoldToParty, Cust, CreatedBy, SONo, SODate, SORDate, LineItemNo, PartNo, PartDesc, Qty, CustomerRequestDate, RoutingTime, SalesP, Zone, Together) VALUES ('"+cell2.toString().trim()+"', '"+val.trim()+"', '"+stp.trim()+"', '"+cell1.toString().trim()+"', '"+cell11.toString().trim()+"', '"+sonum.trim()+"', '"+val1.trim()+"', '"+val3.trim()+"', '"+lnum.trim()+"', '"+cell7.toString().trim()+"', '"+cell8.toString().trim()+"', '"+qty.trim()+"', '"+val2.trim()+"', '"+rt.trim()+"', '"+cell11.toString().trim()+"', '"+cell10.toString().trim()+"', '"+together.trim()+"')");

                    if(k > 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Data Inserted");

                        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("c:\\DCIN_LOG\\dcp_dcl_mfg_order_status\\SQL DATA BASE DCP_2015\\SQL database  DCP.xls"));

                        HSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

                        File folder1 = new File("c:\\DCIN_LOG\\dcp_dcl_mfg_order_status\\SQL DATA BASE DCP_2015\\output.xls");

                        final String fileName1 = folder1.getAbsolutePath();

                        FileInputStream myInput1 = new FileInputStream(fileName1);

                        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem1 = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput1);

                        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem1);

                        HSSFSheet mySheet1 = myWorkBook1.getSheetAt(0);

                        int lastr = mySheet1.getLastRowNum();

                        copyRow(wb, sheet, r, lastr);

                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\DCIN_LOG\\dcp_dcl_mfg_order_status\\SQL DATA BASE DCP_2015\\output.xls", true);

                        workbook.write(out);

                        out.close();
                    }

                    else
                        System.out.println("Data Not Inserted");

                    System.out.println("r after insertion: " + r);
                }

                System.out.println("r after one iteration: " + r);
            }

            success = true;
            stat.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
    }
    System.out.println("Success : " + success);
}

public void copyRow(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet worksheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum)
{
    // Get the source / new row
    HSSFRow newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
    HSSFRow sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

    // If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row
    if(newRow != null)
            worksheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);

    else
            newRow = worksheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);

    // Loop through source columns to add to new row
    for(int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++)
    {
        // Grab a copy of the old / new cell
        HSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
        HSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

        // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
        if(oldCell == null)
        {
            newCell = null;

            continue;
        }

        // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
        HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());

        ;

        newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

        // If there is a cell comment, copy
        if(oldCell.getCellComment() != null)
            newCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());

        // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
        if(oldCell.getHyperlink() != null)
            newCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());

        // Set the cell data type
        newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());

        // Set the cell data value
        switch(oldCell.getCellType())
        {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                                        break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                                        break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR: newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
                                        break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                                        break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());
                                        break;
        }
    }

    // If there are are any merged regions in the source row, copy to new row
    for(int i = 0; i < worksheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
    {
        CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = worksheet.getMergedRegion(i);

        if(cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow() == sourceRow.getRowNum())
        {
            CellRangeAddress newCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(newRow.getRowNum(), (newRow.getRowNum() + (cellRangeAddress.getLastRow() - cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow())), cellRangeAddress.getFirstColumn(), cellRangeAddress.getLastColumn());

            worksheet.addMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dumping code and pictures and asking for a solution is not that helpful.  Reduce your code to the minimum needed to produce the behavior and tell us what you think is wrong.  Then someone might nibble.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... silly mistake, I did it using prepared statement and it worked